# rbind matrices with different dimension and some columns in common in R

Tags: r, matrix

I need your help. 
I'm working with genotypes with 3 files of different sizes (in separate files). 
I need to join the genotypes one underneath the other by the common columns. `NA` genotypes may not appear in the file.

The file would have to look like below. 
Column 1 is the identification of the animal, column 2 is the chip and the other columns are the genotypes coded as 0, 1, 2 and 5.

Could anyone help?

Thank you.

```
1353 1  2110101100201201101101011011111121111121 
8014 1  2111010151110112022111011151111210111221 
516  2  2110510120 
517  2  2210510220
181  3  11101111122011205502
182  3  11201111122012205502
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you post this as a dataframe (use `dput`), and show what you have tried?

Comment: you could try the `merge`, `plyr::join` or `dplyr::full_join/left_join` functions to do this, though it's hard to tell what will suit you without more information on the different datasets you have and the desired result

Comment: Are these numbers separated by spaces in the file or something else? Like a tab? You can turn these numbers into character strings, with space as a separator, but we need to know more. For example, are these numbers in a .txt file?